# Where is the code that reorders the sequenceNumber between product and category?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I've been trying to found where is the code that reorders the sequenceNumber between a product and a category.

If you put a new product on a category, all the sequenceNumber of the other products from that category, are updated.

I need to adapt that logic to my company's needs.

Can you guys help me find which class/method is responsible of that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Not you question answers, but you can use below technique:
Create interceptor for your product type and add breakpoint for sequenceNumber changing in it. Start system in debug mode and make changes then check call stack for finding changer/modifier.